# Converting Haskell Polymorphic Cosine function to F#

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, polymorphism, inline

I'm trying to convert some Haskell code to F# but I'm having some trouble since Haskell is lazy by default and F# is not.  I'm also still learning my way around F#.  Below is a polymorphic cosine function in Haskell with pretty good performance.  I want to try and keep the same or better performance parameters in F#.  I would like to see a F# List version and a F# Seq version since the Seq version would be more like the lazy Haskell but the List version would probably perform better.  Thanks for any help.

Efficiency: number of arithmetic operations used proportional to number of terms in series

Space: uses constant space, independent of number of terms

```
takeThemTwoByTwo xs =
    takeWhile (not . null) [take 2 ys | ys <- iterate (drop 2) xs]

products xss = [product xs | xs <- xss]

pairDifferences xs =
    [foldr (-) 0 adjacentPair | adjacentPair <- takeThemTwoByTwo xs]

harmonics x = [x/(fromIntegral k) | k <- [1 ..]]

cosineTerms = scanl (*) 1 . products . takeThemTwoByTwo . harmonics

cosine = foldl (+) 0 . pairDifferences .
    take numberOfTerms . cosineTerms
```

Comment: Which cosine approximation is this? Is the input in `degree` or in `radian`?

Comment: "the same or better performance parameters". If you care about performance, why are you using this algorithm?

Comment: @JonHarrop If you have a different algorithm that is polymorphic but performs faster I would love to see it.  I'm not saying there is not one, I just don't know one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pad's answer is good, but not polymorphic.  In general, it's significantly less common to create such definitions in F# than in Haskell (and a bit of a pain).  Here's one approach:

```ml
module NumericLiteralG =
    let inline FromZero() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline FromOne() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne    

module ConstrainedOps =
    let inline (~-) (x:^a) : ^a = -x
    let inline (+) (x:^a) (y:^a) : ^a = x + y
    let inline (*) (x:^a) (y:^a) : ^a = x * y
    let inline (/) (x:^a) (y:^a) : ^a = x / y

open ConstrainedOps

let inline cosine n x = 
    let two = 1G + 1G
    Seq.unfold (fun (twoIp1, t) -> Some(t, (twoIp1+two, -t*x*x/(twoIp1*(twoIp1+1G))))) (1G,1G)
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this more easily without the `NumericLiteralG` and `ConstrainedOps` modules, by specifying the type of parameter `x` and the return type of `cosine`? I assume `ConstrainedOps` is used only to clean-up the signature, since math ops are already polymorphic.

Comment: @Daniel - yes, `ConstrainedOps` is only there to avoid lots of intermediate type variables (which are merely ugly but not harmful).  I believe that annotating the arguments and return type would not be sufficient - you wuold also need to annotate `two`, `twoIp1`, etc., which clutters the code.  Without `NumericLiteralG` you would need to plug `GenericOne` in a few places (`GenericZero` is unused and could be dropped).  However, if you're going to be creating other polymorphic numeric code, then both of these modules can be reused and they make definitions much more readable.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my attempt in case you're lazy to read:

```
let harmonics x = 
    Seq.initInfinite(fun i -> - x*x/(float ((2*i+1)*(2*i+2))))

let cosineTerms = Seq.scan (*) 1.0 << harmonics

let cosine numberOfTerms = Seq.sum << Seq.take numberOfTerms << cosineTerms
```

I have a hard time finding out that you're calculating `cosine` in radian using Taylor series:

> cosine(x) = 1 - x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! - x<sup>6</sup>/6! +
>   ...

Let me describe what you're doing:

1. Create an infinite sequence of `x/k` where `k` is an integer starting from `1`.
2. Split above sequence into chunks of two and scan by multiplying with a seed of `1` to have a sequence of x<sup>2</sup>/((2k-1)*(2k)) (with an exception of `1` at the beginning).
3. Split the new sequence into blocks of two again to have differences in the form of x<sup>4k-4</sup>/((4k-4)!) - x<sup>4k-2</sup>/((4k-2)!) and sum all of them to get final result.

Because it's likely to be inefficient to split sequences in F# and `takeThemTwoByTwo` function is not essential, I chose another approach:

1. Create an infinite sequence of - x<sup>2</sup>/((2k-1)*(2k)) where `k` is an integer starting from `1`.
2. Scan the sequence by multiplying with a seed of `1`; we get a sequence of (-1)<sup>k</sup> * x<sup>2k</sup>/((2k)!).
3. Sum all elements to obtain final result.

Above program is a direct translation of my description, succinct and simple. Computing `cosine` with `numberOfTerms = 200000` iterations takes 0.15 seconds on my machine; I suppose it is efficient enough for your purpose.

Furthermore, a `List` version should be easy to translate from this one.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, my fault was to underestimate the polymorphism part of the question. I focused more on the performance part. Here is a polymorphic version (keeping closely to the `float` version):

```
let inline cosine n (x: ^a) = 
    let one: ^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
    Seq.initInfinite(fun i -> LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt (- x*x) ((2*i+1)*(2*i+2)))
    |> Seq.scan (*) one
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.sum
```

`Seq.initInfinite` is less powerful than `Seq.unfold` in @kvb 's answer. I keep it to make things simple because `n` is in `int` range anyway.

Comment: [It was me.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a43kowi2ncI) The OP specifically notes the polymorphism of the Haskell function. Yours is not polymorphic.

Answer (score 4):

As Pad wrote, this appears to be the Taylor series expansion of cos(*x*) about *x*=0:

> cosine(x) = 1 - x²/2! + x⁴/4! - x⁶/6! + ...

So your question is an XY question: you presented a solution rather than posing the problem. Presenting the problem instead makes it much easier to solve it differently.

Let's start by writing a `float`-specific version in F#:

```
let cosine n x =
  let rec loop i q t c =
    if i=n then c else
      loop (i + 1) (q + 10 + 8*i) (-t * x * x / float q) (c + t)
  loop 0 2 1.0 0.0
```

For example, we can compute 1M terms of the expansion of x=0.1:

```
cosine 1000000 0.1
```

The best way to make this polymorphic in F# is to parameterize the function over the operators it uses and mark it as `inline` in order to remove the performance overhead of this parameterization:

```
let inline cosine zero one ofInt ( ~-. ) ( +. ) ( *. ) ( /. ) n x =
  let rec loop i q t c =
    if i=n then c else
      loop (i + 1) (q + 10 + 8*i) (-.t *. x *. x /. ofInt q) (c +. t)
  loop 0 2 one zero
```

Now we can compute 1M terms using `float` like this, which is just as fast as before:

```
cosine 0.0 1.0 float ( ~- ) (+) (*) (/) 1000000 0.1
```

But we can also do single-precision `float`:

```
cosine 0.0f 1.0f float32 ( ~- ) (+) (*) (/) 1000000 0.1f
```

And arbitrary-precision rational:

```
cosine 0N 1N BigNum.FromInt (~-) (+) (*) (/) 10 (1N / 10N)
```

And even symbolic:

```
type Expr =
  | Int of int
  | Var of string
  | Add of Expr * Expr
  | Mul of Expr * Expr
  | Pow of Expr * Expr

  static member (~-) f = Mul(Int -1, f)
  static member (+) (f, g) = Add(f, g)
  static member (*) (f, g) = Mul(f, g)
  static member (/) (f, g) = Mul(f, Pow(g, Int -1))

cosine (Int 0) (Int 1) Int (~-) (+) (*) (/) 3 (Var "x")
```

To make it faster, hoist the common subexpression `-x*x` out of `loop`.