# make function work with all numeric types (int, float, long)

Tags: f#

this simple function:

```
let sum a b = a + b
```

will work **only for int types**

how to make it so that it would also work for float and long  ?

Comment: If you're interested in more details, I wrote an F# math article series, which has an article on writing generic numeric code in F# (it covers `inline`, but also a few more advanced options): http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx

Comment: Make sure you understand why this function is made to work for only one type before trying to write any generic numerical code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx):

```
let inline sum a b = a + b
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you're interested in writing your own polymorphic numerical functions, you should use both [inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx) and [LanguagePrimitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340276.aspx) module.

Here is a polymorphic cosine function from the thread [Converting Haskell Polymorphic Cosine function to F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905037/converting-haskell-polymorphic-cosine-function-to-f):

```
let inline cosine n (x: ^a) = 
    let one: ^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
    Seq.initInfinite(fun i -> LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt (- x*x) ((2*i+1)*(2*i+2)))
    |> Seq.scan (*) one
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: I think inline has a different purpose

Comment: May have a different purpose but it accomplishes what you're looking for.  @pad is right--this is how you do what you want.

Comment: @ChuckNorris: Do you want to write generic numeric functions? It would look very verbose in F#. And you need to find a better example because `(+)` is already generic.

Comment: @pad yes I guess generic is what I'm looking for, basically how else would you do that, without inline ?

Comment: @ChuckNorris : You think incorrectly. Put aside your preconceived notion of what inline means, and read about what it means _for F#_.

Comment: Note that generic numerical code is usually worthless due to the differences in behaviour between numerical types, e.g. associativity, numerical stability...

Answer (score 3):

The example function you give only works for int types because of type inference; the type inference mechanism will automatically infer int because it sees the addition.  If you want to make the same function for float and long, you'd either do inline as Pad has said or you could do this:

```
let sumFloat (a:float) b = a + b

let sumLong (a:int64) b = a + b
```

But *inline* is the right mechanism to get the generic "any type that supports addition" behavior that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
let f g x y = g x y
f (+) 0.0 1.0;;
f (=) 0 1;;
```

I like this solution as well.