# How to prevent type inference from choosing `int` when using operator (*)

Tags: f#, inline, type-inference

I'm attempting to define the following function (sharing space in the Seq module name).

```
module Seq =

    let scale value sequence = 
        sequence 
        |> Seq.map (fun v -> v * value)
```

However type inference is imposing the elements and value be of type `int`. I would like this method to work on integers (8-bit, 16-bit, etc.), floats (single and double), etc.

Why is the type inference jumping to `int`, and how do I keep this function more generic?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192390/make-function-work-with-all-numeric-types-int-float-long.

Answer (score 5):

For normal function declarations, F# will not let you write a function that is generic in the numeric type (generic constraints in .NET cannot express a constraint such as "has * operator")

However, F# will let you write a generic numerical function if you mark it as `inline`. In that case, it will inline the function when you call it and specialize the code to the particular type (and the type system will use *static member constraints* to express the requirements).

```
let inline scale value sequence = 
    sequence 
    |> Seq.map (fun v -> v * value)
```

You can find more information [in a blog post I wrote some time ago](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/).