# How to handle Arithmetic operation OverflowException in F#?

Tags: python, f#

I'm doing Project Euler problem 1 in F#:

> Multiples of 3 and 5
>
> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Here is my attempt:

```ml
[1..999]
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x%3 * x%5 = 0)
    |> List.sum

val it : int = 233168
```

My friend calculated it in Excel by adding multiples of 3 and multiples of 5 extracting multiples of 15, and he challenged me with a larger upper range: find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1234567.

I tried this:

```ml
[1..1234567]
     |> List.filter (fun x -> x%3 * x%5 = 0)
     |> List.sum
```

> `System.OverflowException`: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Second try:

```ml
let mutable result = 0
for x < 1000 do
    if  x%3 * x%5 = 0 then result = result + x
```

> error FS0010: Unexpected integer literal in pattern. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.

To my surprise, Python could handle this well and quite efficient:

```py
sum(x for x in range(1234567) if x%3 * x%5 == 0)
# 355636612814L

%time sum(x for x in range(1234567) if x%3 * x%5 == 0)
Wall time: 401 ms
Out: 355636612814L
```

Question:

1. Why the F# program leads to "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"?
2. Is it possible to write the above python equivalent solution in F#?
3. What's the idiomatic F# way to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that the result is a large number - Python has arbitrary-precision integers (in 2.x they become **L**ong at a certain point, as you can see) but F# doesn't - look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10192390/3001761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use bigint for large numbers, like this

```
[1I..1234567I] 
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x % 3I * x % 5I = 0I) 
    |> List.sum
```

or (less readable)

```
[bigint  1..bigint 1234567] 
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x % bigint 3 * x % bigint 5 = bigint 0) 
    |> List.sum
```

Also for numbers [less then 9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use int64 type (with **L** suffix), using int64 can improve overall performance

```
[1L..1234567L] 
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x % 3L * x % 5L = 0L) 
    |> List.sum
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `int64 (L)` is a good solution. I ran it on my computer and it took `598 ms`. I'm wondering why it is slower than python, given python is interpreted, and F# is JIT compiled?

Comment: by creating a `[1L..1234567L]` you actually create the list and then filter elements (copying the list in the process) and then summing the result. If you use `seq{1L..1234567L}` and `Seq.filter` and `Seq.sum`, that ought to be less memory-heavy and it's quite possible it'll run faster.

Comment: @DanielFabian Yes, `Seq` is faster than `List`, it took `488 ms` on my computer, still slower than Python. Although the execution time doesn't matter in this problem, the performance suprises me. (thank you)

Comment: You can also try use array instead of list (`[|1L..1234567L|]` and `Array.filter`/`Array.sum` instead of `List.filter`/`List.array`). Array will not create iterator (just get value by index) and will work faster. On my machine: list version - `700ms`, array version - `250ms`

Comment: this version should pretty much smoke the python code, in case you feel like becoming imperative: `let mutable sum = 0L for x = 1 to 1234567 do
    if x%3 * x%5 = 0 then sum <- sum + int64 x`

Comment: @segrived The array version took `561 ms` on my computer, almost the same with the List version.

Comment: @segrived Yes, the imperative version took only `21 ms`. May I ask that functional programming which may lead to high level abstraction would inevitablely have performance overhead?

Comment: well, yes and no. Yes there is most certainly *some* overhead, but about 95% of the time it is not relevant. And plus functional thinking allows you to make high-level optimizations, that would not be allowed due to mutable state. That said, when you really need performance, you may on occasion end up rewriting some inner loop in imperative style. (We do heavy number crunching and apart from some matrix mul  loops, we still do everything in a functional style)

Comment: @DanielFabian +1 for `high-level optimizations`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward translation of your Python code runs in half the time, 158 ms (vs 317 ms for Python) on my machine.

```
seq { 
    for x in 0L..1234566L do 
        if x % 3L * x % 5L = 0L then
            yield x
}
|> Seq.sum
```

This arguably more idiomatic code still runs faster than your Python (220 ms).

```
seq { 0L .. 1234566L }
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> x % 3L * x % 5L = 0L)
|> Seq.sum
```

Even a LINQ version is faster (221 ms).

```
query {
    for x in 0L .. 1234566L do
    where (x % 3L * x % 5L = 0L)
    sumBy x
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's `233 ms` on my computer - about half the time of Python. This is reasonalable; and it solved my confused understanding on performance of interpered language and JIT compiled language. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and answer your questions:

1. *Why the F# program leads to "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"?*

Overflow error happens due to the limitation in representable range of 32-bit signed integers (2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647).  Answer when exclusive upper limit is 1,234,567 turns out to be as follows:

```
Sum of all natural numbers up to 1234567 divisible by 3 or by 5 is 355,636,612,814
Result was computed in 12 ms
```

2. *Is it possible to write the above python equivalent solution in F#?*

Here's the complete program that is similar to the Python implementation.  It is written in arguably imperative style, but it gets the job done fast.

```
open System.Diagnostics

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   let limit_exclusive = 1234567
   let limit = limit_exclusive - 1
   let divisor1 = 3
   let divisor2 = 5

   let stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
   let mutable sum = 0UL

   for x = 1 to limit do 
      if (x % divisor1 = 0) || (x % divisor2 = 0) then 
         sum <- sum + uint64 x

   stopwatch.Stop()

   printfn "Sum of all natural numbers up to %d divisible by %d or by %d is %d" limit_exclusive divisor1 divisor2 sum
   printfn "Result was computed in %d ms" stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

   0 // return an integer exit code

Sum of all natural numbers up to 1234567 divisible by 3 or by 5 is 355,636,612,814
Result was computed in 12 ms
```

3. *What's the idiomatic F# way to solve this problem?*

Since F# is a multi-paradigm language, it allows one to express algorithms intuitively or close to the machine, or anything else in between.  I'd like to take an opportunity to outline another approach that might be more intuitive to some, but yields lower performance metrics.

```
   let seq1 = seq { 0 .. divisor1 .. limit }
   let seq2 = seq { 0 .. divisor2 .. limit }

   let both = Seq.append seq1 seq2
   let sum = both
             |> Seq.distinct
             |> Seq.map uint64
             |> Seq.sum

Sum of all natural numbers up to 1234567 divisible by 3 or by 5 is 355,636,612,814
Result was computed in 535 ms
```