# F#: how to define a function to add up 2 floats? Specify "Float" in function signature?

Tags: function, f#, inline, definition

Without type specification, F# function definition seems to receive only int type. I don't want to use generic programming, just want to declare a function to receive 2 floating types, add them together:

```
> let g a b=a+b;;

val g : a:int -> b:int -> int
```

How to change my statement? Thanks.

Comment: posting as a comment as this is almost certainly a dupe.  Should be `let g a b : float = a+b`

Comment: Possible dupe here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192390/make-function-work-with-all-numeric-types-int-float-long, the second answer is correct for this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add type annotation to the result or arguments to change the inferred type to `float`.

```
let f1 x y : float = x + y
let f2 (x: float) y = x + y

val f1 : x:float -> y:float -> float
val f2 : x:float -> y:float -> float
```

Or you can use an [inline function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)

```
let inline f x y = x + y

val inline f :
  x: ^a -> y: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

As you can see the inline function will work with any type that has `+` operator

```
f 1 2
f 1.4 1.2
f "foo" "bar"
```